# onClick reverse functionality

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a way to, reverse an onClick functionality. Basically its a thumbnail carousel having tow buttons right and left to move thumbs left - right. The onClick function for right button works, but not on the left one.

I had copied the exact function and reversed the coordinates but it did not work.

Here's what i have so far ..

```js
$(function(){
 
 $('.right').click(function(){
    
  var width = $('.thumbs').width();
        var left = $('.thumbs ul').offset().left;
        //alert(left);
        //alert(width);
  
  $('.thumbs ul').animate({'left': -width+left } , 1000);
  
 });

 $('.left').click(function(){
    
  var width = $('.thumbs').width();
        var left = $('.thumbs ul').offset().left;
        //alert(left);
        //alert(width);
  
  $('.thumbs ul').animate({'right': width-left } , 1000);
  
 });    
    
 
});
```

```css
•{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body{
 background:#eee;
}
.thumbs{
 width:80%;
 overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 20px;
}
.thumbs ul{
 width:5000px;
 max-width:auto;
 position:relative;
}
.thumbs ul li{
 display:inline;
}
.thumbs ul li a{
 display:inline-block;
 float:left;
    margin:0 5px;
}
.arrow{
 font-size:2em;
 display:inline-block;
 padding:5px;
 background:hotpink;
 position:absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.left{
 top:100px;
 left:10px;
}
.right{
 right:5%;
 top:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a class="arrow left">&larr;</a>
    
    <div class="thumbs">

      <ul>

 <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a></li>
        
      </ul>
    </div>
  
    <a class="arrow right">&rarr;</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still the `left` style that you should change, and the new position is the previous position (in the variable `left`) plus the width of the image:

```
$('.thumbs ul').animate({'left': left + width } , 1000);
```

Comment: wow, superb. :) It works now. is there a way to just animate the contents only? because if you keep clicking its keep animating even though there are no images

Comment: @yaqoob: You would count how many images there are and then keep track of how far the user has stepped, so that you can stop at the last image.

Comment: Guffa my jQuery is no good. i understand what you said, it make sense. But i dont know the code.

Comment: @yaqoob: That's not so much jQuery. You can use `$('.thumbs li').length` to get the number of images, then store it in a variable. Use another variable to keep track of the position, increase and decrease it when the user steps left or right.

Comment: Thanks Guffa. but it still above my head :)

Comment: @yaqoob: Initialise the variables: `var cnt = $('.thumbs li').length, pos = 0;`. When you move in one direction: `if (pos > 0) { pos--; (...animation code...) }`, and the other direction: `if (pos < cnt - 1) { pos++; (...animation code...) }`.

Comment: followed your code, placed the right button Click animation in first condition and the left Click function animation in second condition. The script stops working now.

Comment: @yaqoob: Do you get any error message in the console log?

Comment: No, the console log didn't show any errors regarding this script

Comment: @yaqoob: I first thought that you were scrolling an image at a time so that you could just count them, but as you are scrolling a page at a time you need to check the coordinates instead. Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/k9fxb1hp/

Comment: Guffa: The JSFiddle works perfectly, but when i put that script into my page i got this error in the console `TypeError: jQuery(...).offset(...) is undefined` therefore script stops working :( and the error points towards the very first line `var min = left = jQuery('.thumbs ul').offset().left;`

Comment: @yaqoob: You need to run it in the `ready` event so that the elements exist at that time, i.e. inside `$(function(){ ... });`.

Comment: Thanks alot :) i'm happy now its working as i wanted. thanks for your awesome support

Comment: can you please look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677848/jquery-stop-scrolling-at-the-last-element