# jQuery Stop Scrolling at the last element

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying the make the scroll functionality between thumbnails of a gallery. so far the thumbnails are scrolling, but there's a small problem though. If the scroll reaches at the last thumbnail it keeps scrolling towards right direction (if you are scrolling towards right) same happening with the left part.

2nd problem is that, if there's only one thumbnail that is only one `li` its still scroll.

**The jQuery:**

```
var min = left = $('.thumbs ul').offset().left;
var max = $('.thumbs li').length * 160 + min;

$('.right').click(function () {
    var width = $('.thumbs').width();
    if (left > width - max) {
        left -= width;
        if (left < width - max) left = width - max;
        $('.thumbs ul').stop().animate({ 'left': left }, 1000);
    }
});

$('.left').click(function () {
    var width = $('.thumbs').width();
    if (left < min) {
        left += width;
        if (left > min) left = min;
        $('.thumbs ul').stop().animate({ 'left': left }, 1000);
    }
});
```

**The HTML:**

```
 <a class="arrow left">&larr;</a>

<div class="thumbs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div> <a class="arrow right">&rarr;</a>
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9fxb1hp/1/)

**The Solution:**

The scrolling should stop when it reaches last thumbnail, from both sides (left and right). and if there's not enough thumbails to scroll for, then it should keep still.

Please help, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the boundaries of the movement, and make sure that it doesn't scroll outside that. As it scrolls to a negative position the minimum is `-(sum of images - width of thumbs)`, and the maximum is `0`.

```
var left = 0;

function scroll(dx) {
    var width = $('.thumbs').width() - 40;
    var min = width - $('.thumbs li').length * 110;
    var l = Math.min(0, Math.max(min, left + width * dx));
    if (l != left) {
        left = l;
        $('.thumbs ul').stop().animate({ 'left': left }, 1000);
    }
}

$('.right').click(function () {
    scroll(-1.0);
});

$('.left').click(function () {
    scroll(1.0);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/k9fxb1hp/3/

Right now it scrolls in steps of the full width of the visible thumbs. You could change the `1.0` into for example `0.8` if you want it to scroll 80% of the width.

Comment: thanks once again for the continuous help. This question was originally coded by you so I figured you can answer it :) very much appreciated your help.

Answer (score 2):

You could measure the position of the last `li` in the list by using the [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) selector and adjust the max so it reflects the width of the `li`.

```
var min = $('.thumbs li').position().left;
var left = $('.thumbs ul:last-child').position().left;
var max = $('.thumbs li').length * 110 - min;

$('.right').click(function () {
    var width = $('.thumbs').width();
    if (left > (width - max)) {
        left -= width;
        if (left < width - max) left = width - max;
        $('.thumbs ul').stop().animate({ 'left': left }, 1000);
    }
});

$('.left').click(function () {
    var width = $('.thumbs').width();
    if (left < min) {
        left += width;
        if (left > min) left = min;
        $('.thumbs ul').stop().animate({ 'left': left }, 1000);
    }
});
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timothyjmullen/ad6eaLug/1/).

Comment: That's not what i am asking. I am asking is that, in my provided fiddle, the thumbnails should not scroll once they reached at end (weather they're are scrolled towards right or left)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered an infinitely looping scroll?

```js
$('.arrow-next').click(function() {
    $(".slider").animate({left: "-=25px"}, 600, function(){
        var left = $(this).css('left');
        $(this).css('left', left == "0px" ? "175px" : left);
    });   
});

$('.arrow-prev').click(function() {
    $(".slider").animate({left: "+=25px"}, 600, function(){
        var left = $(this).css('left');
        $(this).css('left', left == "200px" ? "25px" : left);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 150px">
    <button type="button" class="arrow-prev">></button>
    <br>
        <div style="display: inline-block; width: inherit; overflow: hidden;">
    <div id="before" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; height: 25px; width: 50px; background-color:white; z-index: 5; vertical-align:middle;"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 25px; height: 25px; width: 25px; background-color:red; vertical-align:middle;" class="slider"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 50px; height: 25px; width: 25px; background-color:purple; vertical-align:middle;" class="slider"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 75px; height: 25px; width: 25px; background-color:blue; vertical-align:middle;" class="slider"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 100px; height: 25px; width: 25px; background-color:green; vertical-align:middle;" class="slider"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 125px; height: 25px; width: 25px; background-color:greenyellow; vertical-align:middle;" class="slider"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 150px; height: 25px; width: 25px; background-color:yellow; vertical-align:middle;" class="slider"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 175px; height: 25px; width: 25px; background-color:orange; vertical-align:middle;" class="slider"></div>
    <div id="after" style="position: absolute; left: 175px; height: 25px; width: 50px; background-color:white; z-index: 5; vertical-align:middle;"></div>
        </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>    <button type="button" class="arrow-next" style="display:inline-block">
        <</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i'm not looking for an infinite loop, i'm looking for a solution within my code.